# Aggregation of jenkins pipelines

Tags: jenkins, aggregate, microservices, build-pipeline-plugin

The Jenkins pipeline plugin is awesome.
But is it also possible to aggregate pipelines of (dependent projects) e.g. micro-services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the way that @ebnius says where you have little pipeline jobs and a parent which is orchestrating the complete workflow and calling the different pipelines.

Or you can use the Shared Library plugin (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) where you define a step per groovy file for example and you have the entire structure modularized.

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate jobs that run pipelines you could just call `build [job name]` to invoke subsequent pipelines

Comment: sure but is it possible similar to http://concourse.ci/ to get a picture of the status of all the pipelines?

Comment: You could make a job just to aggregate jobs and define each job as a `stage`. That'd let you visualize the entire sequence.